# Cocos2d Sprite performance with bitplanes

Tags: ipad, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

Is it possible to improve performance drawing sprites by reducing the number of bit planes used in their image file? For example if you only used 4 colours and hence image was 2 bitplanes, would cocos2d show and manipulate these quicker than a 24 bit colour sprite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reducing the bit depth and size for your images will definitely improve performance.  You'll be using less texture memory and overall there should be less work for the cpu/memory to do.  Best thing to do is try reducing the size/detail of your images and see how it affects performance.

Comment: Thanks. Have started experimenting and recognize there are some gains to be had. Particularly interested to know if cocos2d/iPhone has specific boundaries of bitplanes numbers/usage. Documentation appears to be light in this area. Would assume that the underlying hardware does have preferences or optimums but would be useful to know.

Comment: No problem Jx.  Definitely there are limitations on what you can use for image size and bit depth but those are pretty high limits from what I remember.  If these are the questions you have more than likely they have already been answered on StackOverflow already or on the Cocos2D forums (http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/).  I can't recall specifics off the top of my head.  Remember that Cocos2D is ultimately OpenGL so you may want to search for some of your answers in that context as well.